# Turning Vanilla Javascript into React app in Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm Turning this Sign in/up Form into a react application, I'm building it through the use of components. I am new to react so I need some help turning vanilla scripts into react components.
Can someone help me code the vanilla js into components (with sliding transition) ?

Vanilla Javascript

```
const signUpButton = document.getElementById('signUp');
  const signInButton = document.getElementById('signIn');
  const container = document.getElementById('container');

     signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.classList.add("right-panel-active");
  });

  signInButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.classList.remove("right-panel-active");
  });
```

and React Component:

```
export const SignForms = () => {
const [ containerActive, setContainerActive] = useState(false);
const signUpButton = () => {
    setContainerActive(false);
 };  
 const signInButton = () => {
    setContainerActive(true);
 };

.....
<div className="overlay-container">
    <div className="overlay">
        <div className="overlay-panel overlay-left">
        <div className={containerActive ?  " right-panel-active" : ""}></div>   
            <h1 className="font-effect-3d">Come On!</h1>
            <p className="font-effect-emboss">Start Your Journey With Us</p>
            <button className="ghost" onClick={signInButton} id="signIn" >Sign In</button>
        </div>
        <div className="overlay-panel overlay-right">
            <h1 className="font-effect-3d">No Account?</h1>
            <p className="font-effect-emboss">No Problem! Just Sign Up Here</p>
            <button className="ghost " onClick={signUpButton} id="signUp">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can understand your problem properly.

Comment: Hey there, it is not clear from your post exactly what your question is. Are you asking us to convert from vanilla js to React? Or are you asking whether the vanilla js and your React conversion are functionally the same? You should be more specific with an actual question that can be directly answered.

Comment: technically speaking both, i want to convert vanilla js into react and see if my react conversion is anywhere near enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were pretty much there. Keep up !!

Following is the working code, i was able reproduce on my sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/devpandya/SamplSignIns/tree/main/?file=/src/SignForms.js

I found 2 issues:

1. The App.css in vanila.js was different then in your React Code. just copy it from your Vanila Code
2. use containerActive state to maniplulate classes in container div.

```html
const signUpButton = () => {
    setContainerActive(true);
  };
  const signInButton = () => {
    setContainerActive(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="signForms">
      <div
        className={`container ${containerActive && "right-panel-active"}`}
        id="container"
      >
```

Thats it.. !!!..

Also there was a extra div added in your overlay, just remove it, no use of it

```
<div className="overlay-panel overlay-left">
        **<div className={containerActive ?  " right-panel-active" : ""}></div>**   
            <h1 className="font-effect-3d">Come On!</h1>
```